# How to Successfully Upgrade lodash: Troubleshooting Upgrade Failures

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, lodash

When attempting to upgrade lodash in a Node.js directory, I encountered the following errors:

Error 1:

```
sudo npm install lodash@latest
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/share/nodejs/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/share/nodejs/package.json'
npm WARN nodejs No description
npm WARN nodejs No repository field.
npm WARN nodejs No README data
npm WARN nodejs No license field.

+ lodash@4.17.21
updated 1 package and audited 1 package in 0.384s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Error 2:

```
/usr/share/nodejs/lodash$ sudo npm install lodash@latest
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "lodash" under a package
npm ERR! also called "lodash". Did you name your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For more information, see:
npm ERR!     <https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limitations-of-npms-install-algorithm>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-20T03_12_36_652Z-debug.log
```

I also noticed that lodash was installed in the /home/ubuntu/node_modules/ directory when I ran the upgrade command in other directories. However, I'm unsure whether I need to update lodash in the /usr/share/nodejs directory, as it's the only directory showing version information when I use npm list lodash. Additionally, I didn't install lodash in the node_modules directory, and I'm not sure what to do with it.

Furthermore, there are many lodash-related files under the nodejs directory. What are the functions of these files, and are they all related to lodash?"

Comment: Are you trying to install lodash globally via npm?

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that you installed package globally.
Once try :`npm update -g <package_name>`

Comment: I used the installation command globally. He downloaded lodash in the nodes of the Ubuntu home directory, but the one in the usr/share/nodejs/lodash directory was not upgraded, and the /usr/share/nodejs directory also tried to use the download command to download, / There are also more lodash in the usr/share/nodejs directory

Comment: Run npm uninstall -g <package_name> and npm uninstall <package_name> to remove package locally and globally. Then reinstall globally and update globally

Comment: Will it affect other nodejs? I'm afraid it will be affected, but you can try the following, if there is a custom one

Comment: It doesn't work, neither the lodash in the Ubuntu directory nor the usr directory has been deleted

Answer (score 1):

my **package.json** file and **lodash version**

[image: my package.json file and lodash version]

To update lodash version simply use command `npm install lodash@<lodash_version>`

for example : `npm install lodash@4.17.21`

after use this command update Easily **lodash version**

[image: after use this command update simply lodash version]

Comment: Ok, let me try it, do I have to modify the json script first?

Comment: /usr/share/nodejs/lodash$ sudo npm install lodash@4.17.21
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "lodash" under a package
npm ERR! also called "lodash". Did you name your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For more information, see:
npm ERR!     <https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limitations-of-npms-install-algorithm>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-20T08_23_39_170Z-debug.log
Modified or reported an error

Comment: you use "npm install lodash@4.17.21 ", not use "sudo npm install lodash@4.17.21" please try

Answer (score -1):

This question touches on some of the complexities of Node.js package management and lodash updates. First, let me explain the error I encountered and provide some suggestions.

**Error 1:**

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/share/nodejs/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/share/nodejs/package.json'
npm WARN nodejs No description
npm WARN nodejs No repository field.
npm WARN nodejs No README data
npm WARN nodejs No license field.

+ lodash@4.17.21
```

This error occurs because there is no package.json file in the /usr/share/nodejs directory. npm requires a valid package.json file to manage dependencies and configurations. To resolve this issue, you can create a simple package.json file in that directory and then run the npm install lodash@latest command again. Here's an example package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "nodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node.js project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  }
}
```

**Error 2:**

```
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "lodash" under a package
npm ERR! also called "lodash". Did you name your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
```

This error indicates that you're trying to install lodash under a package with the same name as lodash. This is usually caused by having a project directory with the same name as the lodash package. To resolve this, you can try the following:

1. Rename Your Project Directory: Rename your project directory to a name different from the lodash package name, and then try running npm install lodash@latest again.
2. Global Installation: If you only want to install lodash globally and not in your project directory, you can use the -g flag for a global installation to avoid conflicts with your project directory. Here's how you can do it:

   sudo npm install -g lodash@latest

Regarding the node_modules directory, it's the directory where Node.js projects store their dependencies. It's typically created and managed automatically, so you don't need to manually intervene with it.

As for the lodash files under the nodejs directory, those may be part of the lodash package or other files related to Node.js. You can use the npm list lodash command to check the current installation status of lodash in your project. If you only want to use lodash in a specific project, you can run npm install lodash within that project directory instead of installing it globally.